# How to combine input:after:focus pure css?

Tags: css

I have an input field which requires specific gradient borders on focus. So, I've created this kind of border as background color on the block and smaller background on :after element. 
It works at the simple block, but doesn't work on :focus.

`.test:focus:after` and `.test:after:focus` are not working.

Is there any solution?

Here is the sample to see what am I talking about http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ajiwk

Thank you!

Comment: You can't apply :focus to a pseudo element as it's not a DOM element.

Comment: You can not even have `:after` on `input` elements, since those do not have content. (It might work in some browsers, but most likely not in all.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 :after pseudo element with input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369868/css3-after-pseudo-element-with-input)

Comment: Well, you can assign two classes to the textarea, set focus pseudo element to one and after to other. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AGzyB

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answers. I knew that it's not so easy. Will try all the samples written here.

Answer (score 13):

You can't do this for elements that can't have HTML content. See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/p87qA/).

One way to do this is by adding an element that can have HTML content, like `span`, and applying the `::after` pseudo-element (or in CSS 2.1, the `:after` pseudo-selector) to that.

[An example using your code is here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jgCab).

A generic example:

#### HTML:

```
<textarea>Text</textarea><span></span>
```

#### CSS

```
textarea + span::after{
    content:"Hello world!";
}

textarea:focus + span::after{
    content:"Goodbye, world!";
}
```

↪ [See this example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ehtd9/)

↪  [More information about the `+` selector in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

Comment: Cool hack, but I wonder if there is a way to get at the focused element's attributes. I was trying to do `input:focus::after { content: attr(placeholder) }`.

Comment: @Max I don't think there's a way to do that. `attr` specifically gets the attributes of the element the selector applies to, or in case of pseudo-elements like `::after` the pseudo-element's originating element.

Answer (score 11):

I realize this is old, but I found this question when looking for my own and the solution listed didn't work for me, though it did put me on track for what did work.

The solution I used is similar, but a bit different.

**HTML**

```
<span class="after-holder"><input type="text" class="edit long" /></span>
```

**CSS**

```
.after-holder:focus-within::after {
        content: 'content';
    }
```

Comment: Good solution but be aware, not fully supported, although pretty decent if you don't need Edge/IE. Works for me though! https://caniuse.com/#search=focus-within

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me when focus is present in input field.

```
.date-of-birth:focus-within::after {
  position: absolute;
  color: #b5d0ee;
  font-weight: 600;
  left: 40%;
  top: 14px;
  content: attr(placeholder);
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 1;
}
```