# after pseudo element not appearing in code

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, css-content

I'm trying to use the after pseudo element to add some effects to a site.

```
<div class="product-show style-show">
  <ul>
    <li>
      ....
      <div class="...">
        <div class="readMore less">...</div>
        <a href="3" class="readMoreLink" onclick="return false;">Read More</a>
      </div>
      ....
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And stylesheets:

```
.product-show .readMore.less {
   max-height: 200px;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.product-show .readMore.less:after {
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 30px;
 }
```

I see the styling for .product-show .readMore.less being applied, but I don't see a ::after notation in the HTML blocks when I'm examining the site from Chrome (latest version)/MacOS. I read that there are sometimes issues with older browsers, but I assumed that I should be able to see at least the ::after pseudo element notation if I was defining the style correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've had the same problem. Just add `content: "";` to show the element.

Comment: Quick note to avoid others making the same stupid mistake I have: if the outer element has `overflow` set to `hidden`, the `:after` pseudo element won't show...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's because the pseudo-element [isn't generated if the `content` value is omitted](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content) (since the initial/default value is `none`).

Specify a `content` value in order to generate the pseudo-element. A value of `''` is sufficient.

```
.product-show .readMore.less:after {
    content: '';
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: I think it would worth noting that :after/:before doesn't work with <input> tag because this tag has no content. Here is link to a question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369868/css3-after-pseudo-element-with-input
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-a-before-or-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field

Comment: Ok so I added `content` to my selector, but when the selector is inspected it doesn't even have `content`!

Answer (score 9):

As per the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content):

> The content CSS property is used with the ::before and ::after
> pseudo-elements to generate content in an element.

This means that if you don't include the `content` property, the `:after` or `:before` element will not be generated.

Add this line inside your pseudo (`:before` or `:after`) selector:

```css
content: "";  // Leave this empty
```

And see how that affects the result.

Just as a note, you could also add text into the `content` property if you want to use the `:before` or `:after` to display text. In many cases though, you would find that you are simply leaving it empty.